# if use session.get(String entityName, Serializable id), Unable to locate persister, but if use session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id), no problem

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

if use

```
session.get(String entityName, Serializable id),
```

return UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister error,

but if use

```
session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id),
```

no error.
I google similar error and most mention the cause is missing the mapping class in hibernate.cfg.xml or missing @Entity annotation in POJO class, but I check that I have all entered, so why still have "Unable to locate persister" error?

the code and setting is as follow:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        .....
        <mapping class="hk.xxx.slis.model.SliInstrPublishing" />
    .....
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

POJO class

```
package hk.xxx.slis.model;
// Generated 19 Nov 2023, 1:53:51 am by Hibernate Tools 4.3.6.Final

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

/**
 * SliInstrPublishing generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "SLI_INSTR_PUBLISHING")
public class SliInstrPublishing implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long instrKey;
    private SliInstr sliInstr;
    private String lastRecTxnUserId;
    private Date lastRecTxnDate;

    public SliInstrPublishing() {
    }

    public SliInstrPublishing(SliInstr sliInstr, String lastRecTxnUserId, Date lastRecTxnDate) {
        this.sliInstr = sliInstr;
        this.lastRecTxnUserId = lastRecTxnUserId;
        this.lastRecTxnDate = lastRecTxnDate;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "sliInstr"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")

    @Column(name = "INSTR_KEY", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public long getInstrKey() {
        return this.instrKey;
    }

    public void setInstrKey(long instrKey) {
        this.instrKey = instrKey;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public SliInstr getSliInstr() {
        return this.sliInstr;
    }

    public void setSliInstr(SliInstr sliInstr) {
        this.sliInstr = sliInstr;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_REC_TXN_USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getLastRecTxnUserId() {
        return this.lastRecTxnUserId;
    }

    public void setLastRecTxnUserId(String lastRecTxnUserId) {
        this.lastRecTxnUserId = lastRecTxnUserId;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_REC_TXN_DATE", nullable = false, length = 11)
    public Date getLastRecTxnDate() {
        return this.lastRecTxnDate;
    }

    public void setLastRecTxnDate(Date lastRecTxnDate) {
        this.lastRecTxnDate = lastRecTxnDate;
    }

}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Configuring SessionFactory Bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="hk.xxx.slis.model" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
```

calling code

```
public SliInstrPublishing findById(Long id) {
        log.debug("getting SliInstrPublishing instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            //SliInstrPublishing instance = (SliInstrPublishing) this.getHibernateSession()
                    //.get(SliInstrPublishing.class, id);
            SliInstrPublishing instance = (SliInstrPublishing) this.getHibernateSession()
                    .get("SliInstrPublishing", id);  // <-- error here
            if (instance == null) {
                log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
            } else {
                log.debug("get successful, instance found");
            }
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

StackTrace

```
11:20:35,411 ERROR [hk.xxx.slis.dao.SliInstrPublishingDao] (default task-5) get failed: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: SliInstrPublishing
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:731)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:3060)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1700(SessionImpl.java:210)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2781)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2768)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1218)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1101)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//hk.xxx.slis.dao.SliInstrPublishingDao.findById(SliInstrPublishingDao.java:91)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.findById(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//hk.xxx.slis.service.PublishService.getInstrPublishing(PublishService.java:1500)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.getInstrPublishing(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//hk.xxx.slis.controller.AdminPublishController.publish(AdminPublishController.java:262)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//hk.xxx.slis.security.WebSEALAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(WebSEALAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: You need to use the FQN as the `entityName` so including the package. Also ideally you shouldn't be using get but rather `find` on the `Session`. Using `get` will result in a lazy proxy being returned instead of the actual object, the actual object will then only be retrieved as soon as you call a method on the proxy.

Comment: yes, this solve the problem, if you post as answer, I will mark this as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't explicitly specify the `entity-name` it will default to the FQN (the full classname of the entity). So you should be using either `hk.xxx.slis.model.SliInstrPublishing` or specify the `name` attribute of the `@Entity` annotation to override this. Like `@Entity(name="SliInstrPublishing")`.

This is also mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/Entity.html#name--) of the `@Entity` annotation.

> (Optional) The entity name. **Defaults to the unqualified name of the entity class**. This name is used to refer to the entity in queries. The name must not be a reserved literal in the Java Persistence query language.